# Expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++, inheritance, forward-declaration

I'm receiving the error:

```
In file included from proprietario.h:5,
                 from veiculo.h:4:
motocicleta.h:8: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

Motocicleta.h:

```
#ifndef __MOTOCICLETA__
#define __MOTOCICLETA__
#include <iostream>
#include "veiculo.h"
#include "proprietario.h"
using namespace std;
class Proprietario;
class Motocicleta:public Veiculo{

public:
  Motocicleta(int nPassageiros, string modelo, string placa, int aFabricacao, Proprietario* pai, int nRodas, int aro);
  ~Motocicleta();
  Motocicleta (const Motocicleta& source);
  Motocicleta& operator= (const Motocicleta& source);

  string toString();

};                     
#endif
```

Proprietario.h

```
#ifndef __PROPRIETARIO__
#define __PROPRIETARIO__

#include <iostream>
#include "motocicleta.h"
#include "caminhao.h"
#include "carreta.h"
#include "carro.h"

using namespace std;

class Carro;
class Carreta;
class Caminhao;
class Motocicleta;

class Proprietario{
protected:
  string nome;
  string cpf;
  Motocicleta* mMoto;
  Caminhao* mCaminhao;
  Carreta* mCarreta;
  Carro* mCarro;
};
```

Veiculo.h:

```
#ifndef __VEICULO__
#define __VEICULO__
#include <iostream>
#include "proprietario.h"
#include "roda.h"
#include "motor.h"

using namespace std;
class Motor;
class Proprietario;
class Veiculo{
protected:
  int nPassageiros;
  string modelo;
  string placa;
  int aFabricacao;
  Proprietario* pai;
  Roda* rodas;
  Motor* mMotor;
  int nRodas;
  };
```

I removed the methods, because if i added those the question will be to long, sorry, the code is in PT-BR.
I saw that the problem is usually is forward declaration.
But i cannot find out the problem, i looked in so many forums but i cannot find out the problem..

Someone can help me?

Need any other part of the code?

Comment: Did you miss the `#endif`s of the Proprietario.h and Veiculo.h or are they just dropped in copy-paste?

Comment: @Shahbaz if it wasn't a copy paste error, the error message would be something along the lines of `expected #endif`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I know, that's why I didn't write it as an answer. I just wanted to mention this as a side error

Comment: LOL, sorry, i really forgot that.

Comment: Motocicleta.h misses the declaration of Veiculo. If you follow the includes carefully (from the original post, when veiculo.h includes proprietario.h on line 4) then you see that when Motocicleta is declared Veiculo is not there yet.

Comment: The motocicleta compiles well, if i add the forward declaration nothing changes.

Comment: Please don't drastically change the code. Post a different question.

Comment: Motocicleta.h includes Veiculo.h.

Comment: By the way, it’s customary to write code in *English*. If nothing else, this makes the code easier understood by people who might help you.

Comment: Again, STOP DRASTICALLY MODIFYING YOUR CODE! Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is the liberal use of `#include` preprocessor directives.  In general, you should only include a header file at the lowest scope at which it is needed and forward-declare everything you can.  You simply don't (shouldn't) generally need full class declarations for header files.  Header files do not generally need to know about implementation details.  You definitely shouldn't been forward-declaring *and* including the header.

As the code stands in the question at the time of writing this answer, you have a circular dependency on veiculo.h (and also on proprietario.h).  As veiculo.h really is needed for the header of its subclass  `Motocicleta`, you should remove the `#include` directives for the classes you have already forward-declared in each of the headers.  You can then include the headers in the source files as needed.